# How to determine if live website is getting payments through paypal

Tags: php, paypal

Currently, we are developing new E-comerce site to replace the current old cubecart website. Paypal sent us notification about the things to comply like the SSL and TLS certification. However,

I'm not really familiar with Paypal payments. How to determine if live website is getting payments through Paypal?

Does this mean if you have Paypal certificate, you are already ready to accept payment?

I have read this article on how to view Paypal certificate but it's quite old article.  http://support.berta.me/kb/online-shop/how-to-get-paypal-api-username-password-and-signature-information

Is this still relevant?

Comment: your asking if your own site is using paypal to take payments?

Comment: You can surely check your PayPal account to see if payments are posted. The SSL and TLS certificates are there to make sure your client's credit card information is safe. If you want an easier way of using PayPal you can just use PayPal express checkout.

Comment: Thanks @smith, I'm asking, is there any thing I can do to check if I'm still receiving payments through paypal

Comment: log in to your paypal account.